# Merging two mp4 files

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ffmpeg

I have two mp4 files. One contains the audio and the other one the video. Now I want to merge them using python.

```
input_video = ffmpeg.input(application_path+"/tmp/video.mp4")
input_audio = ffmpeg.input(application_path+"/tmp/audio.mp4")
ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output(application_path+"/fused.mp4").run()
```

I get a `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` in the third line. I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I tried it with `ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output(application_path+).run()` and got the same error.

I do not have to stick to ffmpeg, but a command-line solution isn't going to work for me, because it will run on other PCs.

Edit:
Full Error Message

```
File "c:\YouTubeDownloader\YouTubeDownloader.py", line 97, in <module>
    ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output(os.path.join(application_path, "fused.mp4")).run()
  File "C:\Users\Michael Hofmann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\Michael Hofmann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Michael Hofmann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Michael Hofmann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

Comment: Whats the value of  `application_path`. I ran the code on my side and works fine (Linux). Seems like there is a problem working out the paths. Are you on Windows? Remember Windows uses `\` for file paths, might be causing some issues

Comment: That would be weird, because I use the application_path like five times before. It is c:\Users\Michael Hofmann\...\YouTubeDownloader  . In YouTubeDownloader I have my python file and a folder called tmp.

Comment: Try to use `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation. Try to put files in a directory without spaces in full name.

Comment: I do not exactly know what you mean, but the path is declared through ```application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)```. And I put the file in C:\ so now the path does not have any spaces. It still doesn't work...

Comment: Could you pates the full error message you are receiving?

Comment: [Have you tried these solutions?](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/392)